# asp.net MVC сохранение состояний

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Люди, подскажите пожалуйста такую вещь. Вот, например, в WebForms некий блок label имеет текст, который был введен в некотором текстбоксе. Далее при обратной отправке / ответе, этот текст возвращается в этот же блок лэйбла благодаря состоянию представления. Но каким образом это сделать в MVC , там же ведь нет состояний представления? Но так понимаю, что некоторый аналог вьюстейта там должен быть, что это такое ??

Comment: нет в MVC никакого ViewState'а - используйте <input type="hidden"...

Comment: А как насчёт сохранения данных в Session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, в MVC нет сохранения состояний, и не надо. Если Вы хотите передать какие-либо данные, используйте:

1. Отправку формы
2. Сохранение в кукисы
3. Передача параметров в строке браузера

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотя мне кажется, что зря они убрали сохранение состояний. Благодаря ним были псевдособытия, это очень помогало.

Comment: Это "сохранение состояний" и есть надстройка над кукисами (или отправкой форм, точно не помню), единственное отличие - это меньшая гибкость.

Answer (score 2):

еще добавлю к предыдущему ответу, как вариант можно также сохранять в localstorage и какие более важные данные - в сессии